# Adding a days to date column

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, power-automate, flow, date-time

I have a document library with two custom columns (Report Date) and (company name). One company name can have few different Report dates. Is there anyway we can get the highest date using Power Automate?

As you can see in the image below Company Name X has two Report Date. How can I get the 30/06/2021 using power automate?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using "Get files(Properties only)" by selecting the order of date column as desc and Top count as 1. You can pass the company name as well in filter query.

[image]

and to get the exact value of Company name and dates , you can use Parse Json

[image]

Comment: Hi Saira, thanks for your message, can we make the output more user friendly?

Comment: It will return you the json format. Do you want to get only the ID or any specific column of that returned row in json format ?

Comment: I still don't know how I get what I need. I need to get the highest date for each company. Each company can have a few dates. I am struggling. I used Select action to get the company name and report date. However, after here, I am unsure how I can get the logic to work.

Comment: You can use 'Parse Json" action after getting the properties. I have edited the above answer